# How to make a Quickly project standalone?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

I have a Quickly project. But now I want it to be independent from Quickly.

How can I do it? How can I run it without typing 'quickly run'?

Answer (score -1):

To run your application standalone, you can build a package. The [Quickly wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly#How_to_Get_Started) describes how to build packages and also how to distribute them to users:

> How to play with package and release:
>
> optional, but recommended to build first your package locally
>
> $ quickly package
>
> BE WARNED: the two following commands will connect to Launchpad. You
>   need to have a Launchpad account and a PPA already created.
>
> For quickly release, you also need a project on Launchpad to which you
>   can bind your work, as well as keys set up:
>
> $ quickly release
>
> or
>
> $ quickly share

Comment: Nope I want to remove Quickly from development phase and change it to something else.